# Eliminar breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

como estan, saben tengo un problema, estoy ocupando Woocommerce con la plantilla StoreFront que ofrecen, quiero quitar los breadcrums en la paginas y me es imposible. Busque en la documentacion y aparece como hacerlo, el problema es que no encuentro el archivo que me dicen.

En esta pagina estan los codigos.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customise-the-woocommerce-breadcrumb/

Answer (score 0):

Si lo ponés en functions.php *(wp-content/themes/-storefront/functions.php)*, también debería de funcionar

*"For the Storefront theme, use this:"*

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce tiene un plugin que te los quita, [pillalo aquí](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-breadcrumbs/).